# How to save in Transaction?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, transactions

Consider this scenario; suppose I have WPF window which have four objects bonded to its controls
(Schedule, Customer, Contract, ScheduleDetails and Signer specifically ) which represent four database tables in the backend database. I want when the user request save for the information he/she entered to be joined in atom operation in another words all saving operation  be in one transaction so either all operations success or all failed.
My question is what is the most efficient way to represent transaction operation in this scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **most efficient** is to use [`BeginTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfh66ye8.aspx) etc on your `DbConnection`, but this isn't convenient, as you must use the same connection, and each `DbCommand` needs the [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.transaction.aspx) setting etc.

The **simplest** is `TransactionScope`, and if you are on SQL-Server 2005 or above, you will rarely notice a significant performance difference between this and `BeginTransaction`:

```
using(var tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    SaveA();
    SaveB();
    SaveC();
    SaveD();
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Here it doesn't matter if `SaveA` etc use the same connection, as `SqlConnection` will enlist into a `TransactionScope` automatically.

Alternatively, let an ORM handle this for you; most will create transactions for saving a group of changes.

One thing to watch; `TransactionScope` relies on services (DTC) that may not be available on all clients (since you mention WPF, which is client-side).

Comment: If you use TransactionScope make sure your target machine has the DTC - Distributed Transaction Coordinator service running otherwise you'll get exceptions.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks. But there's  a relation between DTC and Transaction class -I don't remember when it comes to picture- but I want to avoid the overhead of being using DTC, even though i like the simple form of Transaction class. Is there a way not to be enlisted in DTC transaction?

Comment: Oops, I comment befor you edit. any way  the question is still there.